# Chrome/Firefox extension for screenshots that are wrapped in a browser window

Tags: web-browser, screenshot

We're currently developing a SaaS platform. Part of showcasing our product is publishing and editing a lot of website screenshots.

Is there a plugin / extension or even an external app that can capture the current website and wrap the screenshot around a browser window? 
The Windows `Alt + PrtSc` function is okay but the browser window doesn't always look nice and it's always filled with extensions, other tabs, transparent window borders, etc.
There are a lot of .PSD templates that contain just plain browser UI windows in which you could place your website content. But saving 50+ differently sized screenshots, layering them in PS, exporting them and etc. is very cumbersome.

Also one of our limitations is that we're using a single page app for our content, so automated or online tools would not work - there are no fix URLs, the content is always generated dynamically.

Android Studio / IntelliJ IDEA has a really cool feature where you can make a Screenshot of your Android device and then directly wrap the screenshot around a tablet, even with reflection and save it as .png.  I'm looking for something like that but for websites.

Comment: Workaround: If you're using Chrome, you could ``open link in new Incognito window`` then use ``Alt + PrtSc``. The equivalent in Firefox is ``private window``. These usually don't have a user-customized look, and you could control which extensions to enable. You might prefer a tool that would provide a more generic browser window frame, but I don't know of any

Comment: Do you really mean "wrap the screenshot around a browser window"?  Or do you mean "wrap a browser window around a screenshot"?

Comment: Would you mind linking to those "a lot of .PSD files", so someone could build a software around it?

Comment: https://browserframe.com/ is a site that lets you upload screenshots to add a border around, but it's not an all-in-one extension